# Save and retrieve ASIFormDataRequest from coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, asiformdatarequest

How could I save `ASIFormDataRequest` type request to **coredata** (in any form) and retrieve it back and make it `ASIFormDataRequest` request again.